# Javascript not creating oninput

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I want to create an input through js that will create an HTML element that looks exactly like this: `<input id="amount" class="amount" autocomplete="off" title="amount" value="0" oninput="updateButton();">`

Here is my code:

```
  const parent = document.getElementById('actionButtons');

  let linebreak = document.createElement("br");
  parent.appendChild(linebreak);

  var input = document.createElement('INPUT');
  input.type = 'text';
  input.id = "amount";
  input.class = "amount";
  input.autocomplete = "off";
  input.placeholder = 0;
  input.value = 0;
  input.oninput = updateButton();
  parent.appendChild(input);
```

This outputs the element: `<input type="text" id="amount" autocomplete="off" placeholder="0">`
Note that this does not include the oninput. How do I generate the element in my opening statement?

EDIT
I needed to get rid of the parentheses to make it `input.oninput = updateButton;` it works now.

Comment: Drop the parentheses: `input.oninput = updateButton;`. You want to pass the function itself, not its returned value.

Comment: Tysm! New to js and still learning how it interacts with html.